# KendoUI Edit Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo UI edit option showing some unexpected behaviour, as you can see in the image there is a text box below Server column and 2 below ServerIP column all containing the id of server "SQL" i selected. Problem is when ever i want to show Server IP column this behaviour occurs, both server and server IP are from the same table.

[image: Overlapping Fields in Edit Option]

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EnvironmentPOCO>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(d => d.EnvironmentName).Width(200).Title("EnvirontmentName");

          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.EnvironmentTypeID, (List<EnvironmentTypePOCO>)ViewData["EnvironmentType"], "EnvironmentTypeID", "EnvironmentTypeCode").Width(150).Title("EnvironmentCode").EditorTemplateName("_EnvironmentCodeDropDown");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ServerID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["ServerDetails"], "ServerID", "ServerName").Width(200).Title("Server").EditorTemplateName("_ServerDropDown");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ServerID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["ServerDetails"], "ServerID", "ServerIP").Width(200).Title("ServerIP");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ProjectID, (List<ProjectPOCO>)ViewData["Projects"], "ProjectID", "ProjectName").Width(200).Title("ProjectName").EditorTemplateName("_ProjectNameDropDown");
       //   columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ProjectID, (List<ProjectPOCO>)ViewData["Projects"], "ProjectID", "ProjectDescription").Width(200).Title("ProjectDescription")/*.EditorTemplateName("_ProjectDescription")*/;

          columns.Command(d =>
          {
              d.Edit();
              d.Destroy();

          }).Width(200).Title("Action");
      })
      .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
      .Sortable()
      .Pageable()
      .Filterable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(m => m.EnvironmentID);
                    model.Field(m => m.EnvironmentName);
                    model.Field(m => m.EnvironmentTypeID);
                    model.Field(m => m.ProjectID);
                    model.Field(m => m.ServerID);

                })
            .Read(read => read.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Create(create => create.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
            .Update(update => update.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
      )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this, actually if you want to show 2 fields of the foriegn key, You can make a property in your class.

```
 public string ServerDetailsProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format(" Name: {0} || IP: {1}", ServerName, ServerIP);
            }
        }
```

then call it in your csHTML file like this.

```
 columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ServerID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["ServerDetails"], "ServerID", "**ServerDetailsProperty**").Width(200).Title("ServerIP");
```

Now if you press Edit you want see the unexpected behiour as in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the id and name attribute of the Server IP columns as the Grid is not able to differentiate between the Server Column and Server IP column on Edit.

For your reference I have tried below:

```
      columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ServerID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["ServerDetails"], "ServerID", "ServerIP").Width(200).Title("ServerIP").HtmlAttributes(new { @id="ServerIP_#=ServerIP#", @name="ServerIP_#=ServerIP#" })
```

Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue.

---

**EDIT:**

You can add the dropdown in client template as below:

```
columns.Bound(s => s.ServerID).ClientTemplate((@Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .BindTo((List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["ServerDetails"])
  .Name("ServerIP#=ServerIP#")
  .DataTextField("ServerIP")
  .DataValueField("ServerID")
  .ToClientTemplate()).ToHtmlString());
```

On Grid DataBound event set the grid scripts to load with document as below:

```
function onGridDataBound(e) {
    $('#GridName script').appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Finally set the field to readonly in model meta:

```
 model.Field(s => s.SensorID).Editable(false);
```

For further information have a look at the explaination: **[Dropdown in Column Client Template](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-client-template-using-razor-mvc)**

Comment: I have done some research regarding it, if i want to show two fields of a foriegn key, for e.g ServerID is FK here, and i want to show both ServerIP, and ServerName, Then i have to make a client template. I dont know how to do that if you know please help. And you above solution didn't solve it.